# Show loading during rendering multiple components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have issue where I am loading multiple Vuetify card components based on category selected on top of the page.

The issue is if the array renders +50 cards then it takes significant time to load. I don't mind about loading time it takes but I don't like that the page gets stuck during rendering and I can't use loading indicator.

I have tried mimic the issue here:

https://jsfiddle.net/owa1czqx/2/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">  
  <button v-for="cat in cats" :key="cat" @click="catSelected(cat)">{{cat}}</button>
  <p v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    cats: ['cat 1', 'cat 2'],
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    catSelected(newCat) {
      this.items = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {
        this.items.push(i + '. ' + newCat)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What I would love to have is to give user feedback that the new cards are loading before they render. Is it possible to somehow async render like I async fetch if I load data?

Unfortunately, pagination or autoscroll loading is not valid solution in my case as it will break the set layout.

Comment: Why don't you use two `div`s, one with loading gif and the other with `app`. Just change their visibilities on `mounted`

Comment: Can you modify the jsfiddle so it works? If I use another div, it doesn't work as the page gets stucks on rendering anyway. Process that takes the time is the one that makes all cards to render.

Comment: im not sure if you can actually get around the part where the browser's busy due to rendering

Comment: I was able to get 'loading' message displayed before starting the rendering process. I show the loading meesage and then start rendering with good old setTimeout( () => (//rendering here), 0). The page looses its interactivity during rendering but it is good enough solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your solution to show progress. In addition, don't hide `loading` in the loop, do it right after it is done. Modified methods are in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/3z1o4vqp/):

One method calls `loadSet` via timeout (I don't know why `$nextTick` doesn't work the same way).

```
timedLoadSet(newCat, offset, step) { 
  var vm = this;
  setTimeout(function() { vm.loadSet(newCat, offset, step); }, 1);
},
```

The other does loading stuff

```
loadSet(newCat, offset, step) {
  for (let i = offset; i < offset + step && i < this.count; i++) {
    this.items.push(i + '. ' + newCat);
  }
  this.loaded = Math.round(this.items.length / this.count * 100);

  if(this.items.length === this.count) {
    this.loading = false;
  } else {
    this.timedLoadSet(newCat, offset + step, step);
  }
},
```

And the one, that launches first load.

```
catSelected(newCat) {
  this.loading = true;
  this.loaded = 0;
  this.items = [];
  var step = Math.round(this.count / 100);

  this.timedLoadSet(newCat, 0, step);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. This will show user loading message while it renders all components.

There is just one issue, that user interaction is disabled during rendering but at least feedback that something is loading is given.

Anyway, this solved my issue as my load times are ~0.5-1 sec which won't bother user if he knows that something is loading.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">  
  <button v-for="cat in cats" :key="cat" @click="catSelected(cat)">{{cat}}</button>
  <p v-if="loading">Loading...</p>
  <p v-else v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    cats: ['cat 1', 'cat 2'],
    items: [],
    loading: false
  },
  methods: {
    catSelected(newCat) {
        const that = this
        that.loading = true
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.items = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {
          that.items.push(i + '. ' + newCat)
          that.loading = false
        }
      },0)
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k8eyb4m/22/

Comment: you can split loading by thousands the same way to get progress